# Replace translations from wp-content/languages/ by translations in child-theme wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to replace translation files located in the `wp-content/languages/` folder by files located in the `wp-content/themes/child-theme/` folder? I want to display the translations from the `child-theme` folder. Should I add something to `functions.php` so that the files form the `wp-content/languages/` folder will be replaced by those from the `wp-content/themes/child-theme/` folder?